Символ � вместо кириллицы при создании фикстур (дампа Json файлов)
При создании фикстур (дампа Json файлов) данным способом:
python manage.py dumpdata goods.Categories > fixtures/goods/categories.json

Почему-то не записываются кириллические символы:
[
    {
        "model": "goods.categories",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "name": "��� ������",
            "slug": "all"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "goods.categories",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "name": "����������",
            "slug": "energetiki"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "goods.categories",
        "pk": 3,
        "fields": {
            "name": "���",
            "slug": "eda"
        }
    }
]


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137501/django-dumpdata-utf-8-unicode

Большое спасибо
